# Get WordPress menu number of items

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I was wondering is it possible to get the number of items in a WordPress navigation? I only need the number of top level items. I'm trying to work out the percentage each item should take up in the navigation bar so if I can get the number of items, I can get the percentage. I was originally going to use the Customizer to let the user input the number of items, but it'd be even better if I could get this number automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) and then count the number of items in the array it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `jQuery` or plain css with `flex`.

Here's an example with both:

```js
var $items = $('nav.jquery > ul > li'),
  $itemsWidth = 100 / $items.length;

$items.css({
  'width': $itemsWidth + '%'
});
```

```css
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav.jquery > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  display: none;
}

nav.flex{
  clear: both;
}

nav.flex > ul{
  display: flex;
}

nav.flex > ul > li{
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="jquery">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
      <ul>
        <li>Item 2/1</li>
        <li>Item 2/2</li>
        <li>Item 231</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="flex">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
      <ul>
        <li>Item 2/1</li>
        <li>Item 2/2</li>
        <li>Item 231</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I did think of this, but this relys on JavaScript being enabled, I'd like to do it server side to make sure it works every time instead. If I can't find a way on WordPress to get this information I'll have to do it like this instead though

Comment: Why don't you use only css?

Comment: If you don't want to use css you can add a [Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu) and count the items there.